# Mathematica legitimacy for research papers

Tags: proof-writing, mathematica, research

I'm currently working on an undergraduate research project and am close to a paper/poster.

A portion of my work involves differentiating a large function, which I did in *Mathematica*. From there I used the function `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, and `FunctionExpand` in order to reduce the derivative to a simpler form for analysis.

I was wondering if there is a question of legitimacy in the successive outputs of simplification. Could there be some algebraic error that ruins the equality of each expression. I'm quite confident that my initial function was input correctly.

So I guess my big question is that if I'm doing rigorous mathematical research, is using something like *Mathematica* valid?

I don't have my code included here just because it's really quite long, but if you'd like, I can include it later on.

Comment: Using software to assist your proofs is more widely accepted now. Of course, this depends on the legitimacy of your code, because your code logic could be incorrect.  Technically, the software could be faulty, but using "common place" software will subdue this objection from the community. The history of proofs of this kind date back to the proof of the [Four Color Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). As far as the general acceptance of Mathematica, I'm not sure; but it shouldn't be an issue as long as your code is correct.

Comment: @YLP: Can you use another independent SW like SAGE or Maple to validate the results? That would greatly support your argument and be a cross check of everything.

Comment: The probability of a Mathematica bug affecting your result is less than the probability that a human would make a mistake in doing it by hand.  In this day and age, insisting that you do every calculation by hand is rather like insisting that you write your manuscript with a quill on parchment.

Comment: Double checking and validating your results is wise advice from @Moo. Be especially careful with slowly converging sumations e.g. an example of an inconsistency I found in Mathematica 11.3 a while back: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194955/handling-errors-in-slowly-converging-dirichlet-beta-infinite-sum